# My automatic header with javascript won't close in any page

Tags: javascript, html, header

So a few days ago, I had a small problem.
My website has a header normal menu, and I wanted to made it automated with javascript.
When I try to find bugs I found a little problem you can see in the image:

[image: Problem image]

[image: Normal menu image]

My menu working well all the time but after I created javascript code:

```
        <!-- header begin -->
    <div id="nav-placeholder">
        <script>
            $.get("nav.html", function(data) {
                $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
            });

        </script>
    </div>
    <!-- header close -->
```

This code made my menu load from the nav.html file, okei finally.
When I load my menu from  nav.html it won't work well, but if I use the code normally in the index.html file it works great.

Maybe I miss something?
Only happen in the mobile version, after I press any link in hamburger menu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My first comment:**
You are replacing data in `nav-placeholder` div., which will replace the script. So, keep the script outside the that div.

```
    <script>
        $.get("nav.html", function(data) {
            $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
        });

    </script>

<div id="nav-placeholder">
</div>
```

**About your problem:** 
You are getting all the content from `nav.html`. So when you try to load the content from inside `nav.html`, it won't work as expected. So, make a copy of `nav.html` and name it as `content.html` or so. Then use `content.html` in both files.

Note:
Make sure the path is provided correctly

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! aprecciate so much.

I have changed the code, and you are right no logic in the script is inside the div.

Now about my problem, my `nav.html` only has a menu code.
What do you mean with both files? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @AlbertoDias , What do you mean by : `When I load my menu from nav.html it won't work well`

Comment: I have a website with multiple pages. So to don't change my nav menu every time page by page, I'm using javascript to load automatically header menu so I just need to change nav.html to change the information in the rest of the pages. My problem is when I load my menu is working perfectly, but when I press in any link (mobile version) I have the hamburger menu opened like you can see in the 1st image. And it won't desapear util I don't reaload the page .

Comment: Okei I think it's doesn't detect "mobile-header in css" I will try to fix it!

Comment: Let us know if it works / not works

Comment: The problem was mine I have used  `<header> </header> ` inside the  **nav.html** and it haves a custom CSS code. So what happens is every time I pressed any mobile link menu it load a desktop version of the nav. It means my mobile CSS never load. To fix never use `<header> </header> ` inside the load files if you have custom css.

Comment: Awesome. It happens. No problem